# How to send a GraphQL Query from Node.js to Prisma

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, prisma, prisma-graphql

I just learnt how to create a GraphlQL server using `graphql-yoga` and `prisma-binding` based on [the HowToGraphQL tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/5-connecting-server-and-database/).

**Question:** The only way to query the database so far was to use the Prisma Playground webpage that was started by running the command `graphql playground`.

Is it possible to perform the same query from a Node.js script? I came across the Apollo client but it seems to be meant for use from a frontend layer like React, Vue, Angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, in the end the Prisma API is just plain HTTP where you put the query into the *body* of a `POST` request.

You therefore can use `fetch` or `prisma-binding` inside your Node script as well.

Check out this tutorial to learn more: https://www.prisma.io/docs/tutorials/access-prisma-from-scripts/access-prisma-from-a-node-script-using-prisma-bindings-vbadiyyee9

This might also be helpful as it explains how to use `fetch` to query the API: https://github.com/nikolasburk/gse/tree/master/3-Use-Prisma-GraphQL-API-from-Code

**This is what using `fetch` looks like:**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const endpoint = '__YOUR_PRISMA_ENDPOINT__'

const query = `
query {
  users {
    id
    name
    posts {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
`

fetch(endpoint, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ query: query })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)))
```

If you want to use a lightweight wrapper around `fetch` that saves you from writing boilerplate, be sure to check out [`graphql-request`](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-request).

**And here is how you use Prisma bindings:**

```
const { Prisma } = require('prisma-binding')

const prisma = new Prisma({
  typeDefs: 'prisma.graphql',
  endpoint: '__YOUR_PRISMA_ENDPOINT__'
})

// send `users` query
prisma.query.users({}, `{ id name }`)
  .then(users => console.log(users))
  .then(() =>
    // send `createUser` mutation
    prisma.mutation.createUser(
      {
        data: { name: `Sarah` },
      },
      `{ id name }`,
    ),
  )
  .then(newUser => {
    console.log(newUser)
    return newUser
  })
  .then(newUser =>
    // send `user` query
    prisma.query.user(
      {
        where: { id: newUser.id },
      },
      `{ name }`,
    ),
  )
  .then(user => console.log(user))
```

Comment: Thanks! How would one decide between using `prisma-bindings` or `graphql-request`?

Comment: I think Prisma bindings are usually the preferred way to go as they provide a lot of convenience around talking to a Prisma API. `graphql-request` is a more generic and lightweight approach that you might use very simple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Prisma and want to query it from a NodeJS script, I think you might have overlooked the option to generate a client from your Prisma definitions.

It takes care of handling create/read/update/delete/upsert methods depending on your datamodel.
Also, you can worry less about keeping your models and queries/mutations in sync since it is generated using the Prisma CLI (prisma generate).

I find it to save a lot of coding time compared to using raw GrahQL queries, which I save for more complicated queries/mutations.

Check their [official documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/setup/generating-the-client-rsc1/) for more details.

Also, note that using the Prisma client is the recommended way of using Prisma in [prisma-binding](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-binding) resository, unless:

> Unless you explicitly want to use schema delegation

which I can't tell you much about.

I did not know of the `prisma-binding` package untill I read your question.

**EDIT:**

Here is another [link](https://www.prisma.io/blog/prisma-client-preview-ahph4o1umail/) that puts them both in perspective